# Android Studio's SDK/AVD manager for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-sdk-tools

Android Studio comes with [built-in support](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager) for managing Android SDKs and virtual devices.

[image: SDK manager GUI - image sourced from https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager]

Is there a way to get this functionality in regular IntelliJ IDEA? I have the Android for IntelliJ plugin installed, and the Android SDK command line tools installed.

For comparison: the settings window in IntelliJ 2017.1.14 with no `Android SDK` pane in the side menu.

[image: settings window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in 2017.1.x and earlier versions. This functionality will be merged in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 release (not available at the moment of this answer).

Comment: Nice! I just upgraded to the EAP and have the SDK manager now. I think this is a feature worth mentioning in your blog post (https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/06/intellij-idea-2017-2-public-preview/)